# httpclient post basic authentication

Tags: spring, httpclient, httpresponse

**Is there an easier way to setup the http client for preemptive basic authentication than what described.**
I have to post from my spring boot service to another external service, but this is not possible in my attempt.
What a mistake I made in doing this.

```
CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
            UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user1", "user1Pass");
            provider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);
            HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider).build();

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://91.204.239.42:8083/broker-api/send");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            try {
                httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json));
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
                int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                return statusCode;
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return 500;
```

this stacktrace

```
 org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 91.204.239.42:8083 [/91.204.239.42] failed: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:156) ~[httpclient-4.5.9.jar:4.5.9]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374) ~[httpclient-4.5.9.jar:4.5.9]
```

Comment: What kind of error message do you get from the external service? What's the output of your code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many methods but to no avail. Then I decided to contact the api manufacturer and they would tell me that this api only works if we allow it. He started working when he got permission. The cause of the problem is permissions